# Avoid page break between heading and first list item

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an HTML document, and I'd like to ensure that when printed, page breaks never appear immediately after a heading.

In an ideal world, this would be as easy as setting `.heading {page-break-after: avoid;}`, but most browsers do not support `page-break-after: avoid` (or `page-break-before: avoid`), only `page-break-inside: avoid`.

When a stand-alone element like `p` follows my heading, I can wrap the heading and the paragraph in a `<div class="nobreak">`, and avoid page breaks inside the `.nobreak` elements.

But sometimes, a long list follows the heading:

```
<h1>A list of things</h1>
<ol>
  <li>This is the first thing.</li>
  <li>This is the next thing.</li>
  ...
  <li>Many things later, we reach the end.</li>
</ol>
```

I can wrap the `h1` and the `ol` *both* in a `div.nobreak`, but this is too strict: it prevents page breaks from occurring at any point during the list, when really all I care about is preventing a break right before the first `li`.

For obvious reasons (the presence of the `ol` tag), I cannot wrap just the `h1` and first `li` in a surrounding element.

Any ideas on how to achieve the desired effect here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 h1 { margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom:0;}
 ol, li:first-child { margin-top: 0; padding-top: 0; }
</style>
```

Use the `li:first-child` subclass to style only the first element in a list.

Make sure therebis no other margins or padding between wrapping elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm afraid that on my computer on Chrome, at least, this does not prevent a page break when printing -- it just moves the two elements very close together.